# @LastModifiedDate is not updating when some of the columns are null in spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data

I have one table and in that, I have `@lastModifiedDate` column.

I have a `status` column in the table which is `null` initially and after successful transaction `status` is getting updated.

When the `status` field is updated, `@lastModifiedDate` needs to be also updated but its still showing the same date and time. Can anybody provide me the solution on that one?

Answer (score 3):

Have you noted `@EnableJpaAuditing` with the `@Configuration`?

You should declare `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` with your entity class too.

for more details you can check https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: Yes, I have did that one.